# Updated to Craft CMS 4.2.5 and now the "New Category" button is missing in Control Panel

Tags: categories, control-panel, updates

Like the title says. I've just updated to the latest version while building out a new site in Craft CMS and the New Category button is missing from the Categories screen in the CP. Both when you go to the page directly or via the Lightbox while editing an entry and trying to add a category from a categories field.

Comment: This bug has been fixed. Thanks guys!

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/11977